# Why does Javascript freeze the computer but not C++ or Python?

Tags: javascript

For example, when executing `while(true)print("o");`

Why does Javascript freeze the computer but not C++ or Python?

Comment: This won't _freeze_ the computer. It will _freeze_ the instance of the js engine the is running the code, and maybe the application running  the engine (e.g. browser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part ([web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage) aside) JavaScript is single-threaded. That means that the code you write is running in the UI thread - the same thread that processes user actions. If your code is long-running, then the UI becomes less responsive. In an example like the one you posted above, the UI won't be responsive *at all* because your code will continue to run until killed.

Languages that are multi-threaded allow developers to do longer-running work in other threads so that it doesn't block the UI. This comes with a trade-off of making the code (potentially) more complicated as it has to be robust enough to handle multi-threaded use.